# How to create a Maybe record instead of a record of Maybes in Elm

Tags: record, elm

This may be a simple matter, but I'm writing a function that I want to return a record, and several of the fields require doing things that might fail, so right now the resulting record looks like this (let's say it's type aliased as `MyRecord`).

```
{ field1 : Maybe a
, field2 : Maybe a
, field3 : Maybe a
}
```

However, this does not accurately represent the "real" meaning of what has happened. The underlying goal of the function is to validate as well as reformat some data. So I want to say that if I have a `MyRecord`, I have three fields worth of `a`'s. If I don't have those fields, I want to know that I don't have a `MyRecord`. Logically, then, I want to return a `Maybe MyRecord`, but for the life of me, this is escaping my newish-to-elm capabilities.

Currently, I am creating the record all at once, but that does not work for obvious reasons:

```
{ field1 = maybeProducingFunction1
, field2 = maybeProducingFunction2
, field3 = maybeProducingFunction3
}
```

How can I create this record so that if any of these functions produce a `Nothing`, the whole record is `Nothing`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correct, what you want is to define a type

```
type alias MyRecord =
  { field1 : Maybe a
  , field2 : Maybe a
  , field3 : Maybe a
  }
```

and to create a record only when you have all three pieces of constituent data? The way to do that is with Maybe.map3:

```
myResult = 
  Maybe.map3 MyRecord
    maybeProducingFunction1
    maybeProducingFunction2
    maybeProducingFunction3
```

This will do all the Maybe checks for you and only construct your record if they all have `Just` values.

There is also a similar approach with `Result` that you can take which has the advantage that you can pass along information about which function failed (strictly speaking which was the first function to fail).